# Tossing coin until we obtain a tail that immediately preceded by a head

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

I was reading [Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188652923X), and the following question appears as exercise $23 (b)$ in the 2nd chapter:

> A fair coin is tossed repeatedly and independently until we obtain a tail that is immediately preceded by a head.
>
> Find the PMF and the expected value of the number of tosses.

My question is: if we let $X$ be the random variable that represents the number of tosses until we obtain a tail that is immediately preceded by a head, can we decompose it into two random variables:

$$X = Y + Z$$

such that $Y$ is the number of tossed until a head appears, and $Z$ is the number of tosses until a tail appears (starting from the moment after the head appears).

The calculation of expectations shows that $E[X] = E[Y] + E[Z]$ but is that just a coincidence or what? and If is true can we assume that $Y, Z$ are independent and thus calculating the variance with ease?

Also, are there conditions for such decomposition so one can prove or disprove his solution?

Comment: You haven't defined $Y$ and $Z$ appropriately. Let's say in the first toss you have a head. Then $Y=1$. In the second toss you see a tail, then $Z=2$. However you haven't yet seen a second head or tail.

Comment: Defining $X,Y,Z$ as in the question, $E[X] \neq E[Y]+E[Z].$ Why would you think this was an equation?

Comment: @cookiemonster I was intended to write that Z is the number of tosses until a tail appears starting after a head appears, and by using the memorylessnes it is just another experiment that Z happened in. so in your example the experiment for Z start from the tail and therefore Z = 1.

Comment: @DavidK E[x] = 4 (by usual calculations), E[Y] = 2 (Geometric with p = 1/2), E[Z] = 2 (Geomtric with p = 1/2).

Comment: Perhaps you can include your calculations for $E[X]$ in the question. For the mass function of $X$ I have $p_X(2) = \frac12,$ $p_X(3) = \frac14,$ $p_X(4) = \frac18,$ and so forth, from which $E(X)=3.$

Comment: Perhaps the point of confusion is that the title doesn't match the rest of the question. The title says "tail immediately preceded by a head" but the question from the book and your repetition of it in the next paragraph both say "two consecutive heads or two consecutive tails." My previous comment was based on the text of the question (where $X$ is defined), not the title (where $X$ is not defined).

Comment: @DavidK You're absolutely right! I am sorry for this huge mistake in the typing. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> such that Y is the number of tossed until a head appears, and Z is the number of tosses until a tail appears (starting from the moment after the head appears).

- None of the tails *before* the *first head* can follow a head.
- All of the results *between* that first head and the next tail will be heads.
- Therefore *that* tail *will be* the first tail to follow a head; and it shall be immediately.
- Thus $Y + Z$ is the count of tosses until the first tail to immediately follow a head.

Use the Linearity of Expectation and the Law of Total Probability:

$$\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(Y)+\mathsf E(Z)$$

$$\mathsf P(X=k)=\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} \mathsf P(Y=j, Y+Z=k)$$

Additionally, since the toss of each coin is independent, the variables $Y$ and $Z$ are likewise independent as they represent counts for disjoint sequences of tosses (ie: the count for $Z$ proceeds only after the count for $Y$ terminates.)  So indeed:

$$\mathsf{Var}(X) = \mathsf {Var}(Y)+\mathsf {Var}(Z)$$

---

As you have noted: Both $Y$ and $Z$ follow a $\mathcal{Geo}_1(1/2)$ distribution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to enumerate potential sequences and look for a pattern.

HH, TT
HTT, THH
HTHH, THTT

$E[X] = \frac 12\cdot 2 + \frac 14\cdot 3+\frac 18\cdot 4+\cdots$

And resolve this infinite series.

$E[X] = 3$

Whatever the first flip is, you have a $\frac 12$ probability of getting a match on the second flip, and $\frac 12$ of being the same distance from completion as you were just one flip before.

$E[X] = 1+\frac 12 + \frac 12E[X]\\
E[X] = 3$

Comment: There was a mistake in the question and I have edited it, please consider reading the question again.